# Weird interaction with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

So, I have discovered something that's been bugging me for a while. I  am still new to C language.

The code that I am talking about is here and its an implementation of strcmp : http://pastebin.com/VeHGm8sD

The weird thing about this program is that if you change at lines 12 respectively 13

```
*first_string++;    // should increment value of char ??
*second_string++;
```

to

```
first_string++;  // should increment address 
second_string++;
```

They both increment the address however. How is that possible ?

Comment: Read up on [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).  The precedence of the postincrement operator is at the very top of the chart, above that of the dereferencing operator.

Comment: It's hard to understand what was intended by `*first_string++;`. Clearly they wanted to increment `first_string`. So why is the `*` there at all?

Comment: That's a good point, @DavidSchwartz.  The linked `strcmp()` implementation appears a bit butchered -- as if a more compactly written version had been clumsily rewritten in an attempt to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of the operator precedence.

That form would increment the char:

```
(*first_string)++;
```

or

```
++*first_string;
```

as @JonathanLeffler pointed. In this particular case it is not important when the char pointed by `first_string` gets incremented as you prematurely drop the result by terminating the statement. In all other cases when this expression is a sub-expression of some other expression you should clearly understand which form of `++` you use.

In your example the `*first_string++` has a value and type of char, while `first_string++` is a pointer

Comment: Seems pretty obvious now. Rookie mistake. I assumed * has precedence.Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

The magic here is [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

`*var++` is equivalent to `*(var++)`.